# Bulbs - to plant or not to plant?

Tags: planting, bulbs, storage

I found some bulbs lying on the ground in my moms garden. They are probably bulbs of lily of the valley or grape hyacinth. They are dry on the outside and look healthy to me. They have a diameter between 0.5cm and 2cm.

I live on the northern hemisphere and it is almost june (the lily of the valley is blooming now, while the grape hyacinth has already bloomed).

Is it better to plant the bulbs now? Maybe in a pot and water them during summer? Or should I rather store them in a cold, dry place until october/november and plant them then?

Comment: Lily of the valley can be quite invasive.

Comment: Lily of the valley is not a bulb, but a root, so the bulbs cannot be lily of the valley.

Comment: then it should be the grape hyacinth, the bulbs look similar, i just didn't know they could be this small (the ones I had seen before were at least 2x as large as these)

Comment: Heh heh. Did you ever play the computer game "The SIMS"? Maybe you found an extra rare plant that will grow into something special.

Answer (score 3):

You can just plant them. After all, the second year (unless you are one of those folks with too much time and money that rips them all out after 1 bloom) they sit in the soil all summer and fall after blooming in the spring.